# Is it possible to know which cascade has been selected?

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, cascade

Is it possible to know which cascade (cascadeid) has been selected in the following tkinter code?

```
popup = Menu(root, tearoff=0)


submenu = Menu(popup, tearoff=0)


def com(cascadeid):
    pass # Doing something with cascadeid


submenu.add_command(label="command1", command=lambda: com(cascadeid))
popup.add_cascade(label="cascade1", menu=submenu)
popup.add_cascade(label="cascade2", menu=submenu)


def do_popup(event):
    popup.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root, 0)


window.bind("<ButtonRelease-3>", do_popup)
```

In order to minimize the number of lines of code tkinter I needed to know which cascade has been selected in a popup menu. I've searched on Google and I haven't found anything.

Comment: Edit the question for the [mre] guide.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend that a submenu widget is shared for multiple menu entries, because it is an undocumented feature. Alternatively, create and reuse a function to create submenus like the following. You can use a closure to access the submenu identifier.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

popup = tk.Menu(root, tearoff=0)

def create_submenu(id):
    submenu = tk.Menu(popup, tearoff=0)
    def com():
        print(id, "command1")
    submenu.add_command(label="command1", command=com)
    return submenu

popup.add_cascade(label="cascade1", menu=create_submenu("cascade1"))
popup.add_cascade(label="cascade2", menu=create_submenu("cascade2"))

root.bind("<3>", lambda e: popup.tk_popup(e.x_root, e.y_root))
root.mainloop()
```

But if you insist to share a submenu, you can use the `<<MenuSelect>>` event like the following.

```
popup_current_label = None
def on_over_popup_entry(e):
    global popup_current_label
    label = popup.entrycget('active', 'label')
    if label:
        popup_current_label = label
popup.bind('<<MenuSelect>>', on_over_popup_entry)
```

Comment: I am going to use your second solution, it works perfectly.